# How to group a list in excel?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a list of lists in Excel. There is some specifications (name, age, country, etc) in the first column and values in the second column. I don't want to repeat the same specifications over and over again. What I want to show in the picture. I tried `=VLOOKUP()` but it did not work perfectly because the lists do not include the same specifications. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Both are possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VBA macro can generate the results, **and also** the list of parameters for the first column of results.

To enter this Macro (Sub), <kbd>alt-F11</kbd> opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select **Insert/Module** and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

Be sure to set the Reference as stated in the Note in the macro

To use this Macro (Sub), <kbd>alt-F8</kbd> opens the macro dialog box. Select the macro by name, and <kbd>RUN</kbd>.

This macro generates the list with the parameter list in the first column.  It could be easily rewritten to have the parameter list in the first row, if that is preferable.

---

```
Option Explicit
'Set Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Sub GroupLists()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim dictParams As Dictionary
    Dim sParam As String
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long
    Dim V As Variant

Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 5)

With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=2)
End With

'Get unique list of Parameters with row number
'Also count the number of entries for number of columns in final result
J = 0
Set dictParams = New Dictionary
K = 0 'row number for parameter
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    J = J + 1 'column count
    Do
        If Not dictParams.Exists(vSrc(I, 1)) Then
            K = K + 1
            dictParams.Add Key:=vSrc(I, 1), Item:=K
        End If
        I = I + 1
        If I > UBound(vSrc) Then Exit Do
    Loop Until vSrc(I, 1) = ""

    If I > UBound(vSrc) Then Exit For
Next I

'Create results array
ReDim vRes(1 To dictParams.Count, 1 To J + 1)

'Populate Column 1
For Each V In dictParams.Keys
    vRes(dictParams(V), 1) = V
Next V

'Populate the data
J = 1 'column number
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    J = J + 1
    Do
        sParam = vSrc(I, 1)
        vRes(dictParams(sParam), J) = vSrc(I, 2)
        I = I + 1
        If I > UBound(vSrc) Then Exit Do
    Loop Until vSrc(I, 1) = ""

    If I > UBound(vSrc) Then Exit For
Next I

'Write the results
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2))
rRes.EntireColumn.Clear
rRes = vRes

End Sub
```

---

**EDIT:** Macro modified to reflect the "real data"

Please note:  You will need to add a second worksheet for the results.  I named it "Sheet2"

---

```
Option Explicit
'Set Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Sub GroupLists()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim dictParams As Dictionary
    Dim sParam As String
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim sDelim As String 'Differentiates each record

Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet2")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=2)
    sDelim = vSrc(1, 1)
End With

'Get unique list of Parameters with row number
'Also count the number of entries for number of columns in final result
J = 0
Set dictParams = New Dictionary
K = 0 'row number for parameter
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    J = J + 1 'column count
    Do
        If Not dictParams.Exists(vSrc(I, 1)) Then
            K = K + 1
            dictParams.Add Key:=vSrc(I, 1), Item:=K
        End If
        I = I + 1
        If I > UBound(vSrc) Then Exit Do
    Loop Until vSrc(I, 1) = sDelim

    If I > UBound(vSrc) Then
        Exit For
    Else
        I = I - 1
    End If
Next I

'Create results array
ReDim vRes(1 To dictParams.Count, 1 To J + 1)

'Populate Column 1
For Each V In dictParams.Keys
    vRes(dictParams(V), 1) = V
Next V

'Populate the data
J = 1 'column number
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    J = J + 1
    Do
        sParam = vSrc(I, 1)
        vRes(dictParams(sParam), J) = vSrc(I, 2)
        I = I + 1
        If I > UBound(vSrc) Then Exit Do
    Loop Until vSrc(I, 1) = sDelim

    If I > UBound(vSrc) Then
        Exit For
    Else
        I = I - 1
    End If
Next I

'Write the results
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2))
rRes.EntireColumn.Clear
rRes = vRes

End Sub
```

---

**EDIT2:**  This macro is a modification of the above, which lists the results in the opposite orientation.  It may be more useful.

---

```
Option Explicit
'Set Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Sub GroupListsVertical()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim dictParams As Dictionary
    Dim sParam As String
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim sDelim As String 'Differentiates each record

Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet3")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=2)
    sDelim = vSrc(1, 1)
End With

'Get unique list of Parameters with row number
'Also count the number of entries for number of columns in final result
J = 0
Set dictParams = New Dictionary
K = 0 'column number for parameter
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    J = J + 1 'row count
    Do
        If Not dictParams.Exists(vSrc(I, 1)) Then
            K = K + 1
            dictParams.Add Key:=vSrc(I, 1), Item:=K
        End If
        I = I + 1
        If I > UBound(vSrc) Then Exit Do
    Loop Until vSrc(I, 1) = sDelim

    If I > UBound(vSrc) Then
        Exit For
    Else
        I = I - 1
    End If
Next I

'Create results array
ReDim vRes(1 To J + 1, 1 To dictParams.Count)

'Populate row 1
For Each V In dictParams.Keys
    vRes(1, dictParams(V)) = V
Next V

'Populate the data
J = 1 'row number
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    J = J + 1
    Do
        sParam = vSrc(I, 1)
        vRes(J, dictParams(sParam)) = vSrc(I, 2)
        I = I + 1
        If I > UBound(vSrc) Then Exit Do
    Loop Until vSrc(I, 1) = sDelim

    If I > UBound(vSrc) Then
        Exit For
    Else
        I = I - 1
    End If
Next I

'Write the results
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2))
rRes.EntireColumn.Clear
rRes = vRes
rRes.EntireColumn.AutoFit


End Sub
```

---

Comment: Not worked. It says "compile error use defined type not defined" and highlights "dictParams As Dictionary" part.

Comment: @t.ztrk That will happen if you do not set the Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime as stated in my response and in the notes in the macro.  Did you set that reference?  You do that under `Tools/References` in the VBE Menu bar

Comment: I tried it but it wasn't active. Restarted everything and now works fine but results not what i was looking for. It returned just last parameters not all.

Comment: @t.ztrk Then I suspect something different about what you have presented and what your real data (or desired results) look like.  Here the results appear exactly as you show them in your example.  Please post a link to a workbook that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: thank you for your help. I may have been misleading when I came up with an example because of I am new to excel. here is my data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4uA3_GELofgZncwemNjNm42aVE

Comment: @t.ztrk Yes, that makes a great deal of difference.  In your original, the delimiter between each group was a blank row.  In your real data, there is no blank row.  I used the Serial Number as the delimiter, but that required some other modifications.  I will Edit my answer.

Comment: @t.ztrk Running the modified macro on your data, it takes less than 1 second to process the worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

Use following `ARRAY` formulas.

***Cell F2 formula***

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$20,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$20=$E2,ROW($B$1:$B$20),""),COLUMN(A:A))),"")
```

***Cell E19 formula***

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$20,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$20=$E2,ROW($B$1:$B$20),""),COLUMN(A:A))),"")
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.

[image]

Comment: Not worked, it just returned list of 0. If that formula checks list and colums maybe works but i need to transform that list to these squares.And i have 20k row in each column.